# How do I make jOOQ generate a "delete [table].*"?

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I've created this jOOQ query to delete certain rows from a table :

```
    DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(c, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
    ctx.deleteFrom(table("filestorage").as("fis"))
      .where(
        field("fis.file_id").eq(storageAudioFile.getId().toString())
        .and(field("fis.scheme").eq(storageAudioFile.getScheme()))
        .and(field("fis.updated").eq(storageAudioFile.getUpdated()))
      ).limit(1).execute();
```

This generates a query starting with `delete fis from [...]` instead of `delete fis.* from [..]` :

```
delete `fis` from filestorage as `fis` where (fis.file_id = ? and fis.scheme = ? and fis.updated = ?) limit ?
```

I can't find much in the documentation for this, and I've tried to modified the `table("filestorage")` with various different syntaxes - but with no luck.

How do make jOOQ generate `delete fis.* from [...]` in this query?

Comment: What's the purpose of this syntax in MySQL?

Comment: @LukasEder the purpose is to delete all rows matching the query criteria, if that's what you mean. I don't really mind if it generates `delete fis.* from [...]` or just `delete from [...]` - as long as MySQL doesn't give an error :-)

Comment: @LukasEder it appears this boils down to my own stupidity. I cannot use `limit` in combination with multi-table delete. My query is not *really* a multi-table delete, but MySQL interprets it as one because I'm using the `delete [table] from [...]`. That is 
why it fails.

So it really has nothing to do with jOOQ, but rather with using `limit` in combination with multi-table delete syntax.

Comment: You can answer your own question here on Stack Overflow. Perhaps someone else will find this useful, in the future